# How to request the number of nrpe plugins installed on the client server

Tags: linux, monitoring, nagios, nrpe

I have a monitoring server with check_nrpe plugin installed and a remote server which I am trying to monitor. The remote machine has NRPE plugin and several commands installed. Can I ask the remote server how many and what kind of commands has it installed?

Answer (score 2):

Don't think there is a straight forward way to check number of commands installed on the remote server, instead you can write a plugin which greps for a specific pattern `grep "command[USEREGEX]" | wc -l` with the **nrpe.cfg** which gives you number of commands within the remote host/server